# Remove the margins from standalone legend ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, r-markdown, plotly

I am making a rmarkdown document in which I want to display a ggplot chart using ggplotly and include the legend below it.

To that end, I extract the legend from the ggplot chart using the approach explained in:
[ggplot separate legend and plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539348/ggplot-separate-legend-and-plot)

The problem I find is that the "margins" (or the canvas) of the legend are huge and the legend is shown far away from my main plot. I would like to remove those margins so the plot and the legend are displayed next to each other.

I tried the functions `viewport()` and `grid.newpage()`, but, I do not really understand what is going on under the hood when drawing a grob.

Is there a way to remove the margins from the legend?

Next I include the reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Stackq"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE,echo=FALSE}
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)

df<-data.frame(x=runif(1000),y=runif(1000),z=rnorm(1000))

#function to extract the legend
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){ 
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot)) 
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box") 
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]] 
  return(legend)} 


```

```{r plotlyfig,echo=FALSE}
rf <- colorRampPalette(rev(brewer.pal(11,'Spectral')))
r <- rf(32)
p1 <-ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y,z=z))+ coord_fixed(ratio=1)+
  stat_summary_hex(bins=100)+scale_fill_gradientn(colours=r)+ theme(legend.position="bottom")

p1leg<-g_legend(p1)
#using cowplot (the issue seems to be the same)
#p1leg<-cowplot::get_legend(p1)

p1<-p1+ theme(legend.position="none")

#print as ggplotly
ggplotly(p1)
```

```{r standalone_leg,echo=FALSE}
grid.draw(p1leg)
```
````

Comment: Perhaps `cowplot::get_legend` can be useful here.

Comment: I tried and apparently the same problem remains. I edit the question including this option.