# Fix ggplot panel width in RMarkdown doc

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, r-markdown

I'd like to align the width of the panel in some ggplots in an RMarkdown document. I can do it by moving the legend to the top or bottom, but that's not ideal. Is there a way to specify panel width with the legend to the right?

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b"), fill = c("short", "labels"))
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

```{r}
d$fill <- c("Now the labels are longer", "which compresses the plotting area")
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) + 
  geom_bar()
```
````

Produces:
[image: html output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to extract the legend and lay it out as a separate grob (graphical object) using `grid.arrange` from the the `gridExtra` package. That way, you get the same panel size for the plot area of both plots so long as the `widths` argument is the same in `grid.arrange` for both plots.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)

# Extract the plot legend as a separate grob
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539348/ggplot-separate-legend-and-plot
g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  legend
}

thm = theme(legend.justification="left")

widths = c(8,5)
```

```{r}
d <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b"), fill = c("short", "labels"))
p1 = ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  thm

leg = g_legend(p1)

grid.arrange(p1 + guides(fill=FALSE), leg, widths=widths)
```

```{r}
d$fill <- c("Now the labels are longer", "which compresses the plotting area")
p1 = ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  thm

leg = g_legend(p1)

grid.arrange(p1 + guides(fill=FALSE), leg, widths=widths)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works great. For plots that don't have a legend, `grid.arrange(p, nullGrob(), widths = widths)` is needed.

Comment: Also, for html_notebook output at least, the `grid.arrange` line has to be in a different code chunk than the `g_legend` call or an empty canvas shows up.

Comment: If you don't have a legend, you actually don't need `nullGrob()`. You can just do this: `grid.arrange(p, widths=widths)`. The `widths` argument results in the same spatial layout even if there isn't a second explicit grob.

Answer (score 2):

`egg::set_panel_size` might help. It's a bit inconvenient though because you'll need to adjust the chunk's fig.width accordingly, which requires creating the plots in an earlier chunk.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(egg)
library(grid)
d <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b"), fill = c("short", "labels"))
p1 <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) + geom_bar()
d$fill <- c("Now the labels are longer", "which compresses the plotting area")
p2 <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) + 
  geom_bar()
g1 <- egg::set_panel_size(p1, width=unit(4,"in"))
g2 <- egg::set_panel_size(p2, width=unit(4,"in"))
w1 <- convertWidth(sum(g1$widths), "in", TRUE)
w2 <- convertWidth(sum(g2$widths), "in", TRUE)
```

```{r, fig.width=w1}
p1
```

Some text.

```{r,fig.width=w2}
p2
```
````

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Unfortunately when output is html_notebook the variable-referenced `fig.width`s don't seem to be respected.

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages that allow you to arrange plots as desired.
Take a look at `egg:ggarrange` function.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(egg)


d <- data.frame(x = c("a", "b"), fill = c("short", "labels"))
p1 <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) + 
  geom_bar() 
```

```{r}
d$fill <- c("Now the labels are longer", "which compresses the plotting area")
p2 <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, fill = fill)) + 
  geom_bar() 
```

```{r}
grid.draw(ggarrange(p1, p2, heights = c(1, 1)))
```
````

[image: ggarrange example]